# Is there a way to use an SSIS Merge Join with a SQLServer OLEDB source and MySQL/ODBC source

Tags: mysql, sql-server, sorting, collation, ssis-2012

I’m using SQL Server 2012 and need to do a full outer join using the Merge Join in order to do delta updates/inserts/deletes.

We would really like to avoid using the sort transformation as it is fully blocking but I’m running out of ideas.

Both source outputs are sorted using order by clauses and the IsSorted property set to true/columnSort order set to 1.

The Character set of the MySQL database is UTF8 And in the order by clause of the source query I am collating using UTF8_bin

The collation of the SQLServer database is SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS but in the order by clause within the source query I have collated to Latin1_General_bin (so the sort methods are the same)

However I am finding that the sets are not joining correctly. Most records do match but I have instances where values exist on the left and right side but the opposite side of the join is null (in theory they should match)

The Values we are trying to match on are in the following format(99999-99999-9999 AAA BBB CCC)

I am aware that UTF8 support in SQL server had not been introduced until SQL Server 2019 so could this be the issue. Are we inevitably going to have to use the Sort transformation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have managed to solve this after doing some research into character encodings.

MySQL UTF8 is more centred around linux and UNIX, Windows UTF8 support is very limited so UTF8 collations are likely to cause issues.

However Windows does support UTF16... It still isn't straight forward though.

In MySQL there are character sets UTF16 and UTF16LE. The LE stands for little endian. UTF16 uses big endian which in short will order by the most significant value in a sequence as opposed to little endian which orders by the least significant value in a sequence. For more info read the below.

[https://searchnetworking.techtarget.com/definition/big-endian-and-little-endian][1]

The encoding used by Windows Servers will mainly use little endian because as explained in the above article, it is determined by the CPUs of the servers (Intel processors are an example that use little endian).

With this in mind I collated the Join/Sort column (nvarchar(55)) in the SQL Server Source to Latin1_General_Bin which in theory should be UTF16 little endian Encoding.

I then converted the Join/Sort Columns in the MySQL source to UTF16LE character set and in the Order By Collated to UTF16LE_Bin

```
SELECT
CONVERT(UPPER(CONCAT_WS('-', Column1, Column2, Column3, 'AAA BBB CCC')) USING UTF16LE) AS DerivedColumn,
...
...
ORDER BY DerivedColumn COLLATE UTF16LE_bin;
```

This Sorted the data correctly without need for using the Sort Transformation.

Answer (score 0):

If you trust the sorting from both sources, you can just set the "Is Sorted" property in the Advanced Edit section for outputs from your data source. You then set a position for any column that the sort is applied to. If there's only one column that it's sorted on, just put a 1 against that column.

Be careful though as it will barf if it isn't in the same order. If it's a number, you'r probably fine, or that format you've mentioned is also probably fine. But strings in general, I wouldn't trust.

Comment: We have set isSorted to true and only join on one column with the the sort position is set to 1. My concern is that when we do perform the merge join, results that exist in both sets are not joining together despite the values being identical. With the MySQL database character set as UTF8 and UTF8 support in SQL server only just being brought in to SQL server 2019, I fear that the only way to get a matching sort order is to use the highly inefficient sort transformation after both Source components. If there is a way around it not using the SSIS sort then That would be really ideal.

Comment: Hi Michael, yes, that's my concern too. I don't think you can trust those combinations. The UTF-8 support in SQL Server 2019 is very basic anyway, and keep in mind that SSIS hasn't changed since long before it was introduced.

Comment: Thank you Greg, I really appreciate your comments.

Comment: Just to inform you Greg that i have found a resolution. I will detail it shortly